# Oracle 11g: Is it possible to create a clustered unique index?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

To create a clustered unique index in MS SqlServer we can use:

```
ALTER TABLE           FOOBAR
ADD   CONSTRAINT      FOOBAR_UK
UNIQUE  CLUSTERED     ( SOME_COLUMN_1, SOME_COLUMN_2, SOME_COLUMN_3 )
```

Is there something similar in Oracle? (I think not but I need to be sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called [index organized table](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/indexiot.htm). [See also the syntax rules](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54492). Your example might be translated to this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foobar (
  some_column_1 ..,
  some_column_2 ..,
  some_column_3 ..,
  some_column_4 ..,

  CONSTRAINT foobar_uk PRIMARY KEY (some_column_1, some_column_2, some_column_3)
)
ORGANIZATION INDEX
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. Would you be kind enough to provide an example with an alter table statement as well? Moreover is it possible to have more than one clustered index in one table? (think not but just making sure)

Comment: @xDisruptor: I don't think it exists. The table layout (heap or index organised) has to be decided when the table is created.